# What are end points in an API

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, api, postman

I have the following description of an API. How do I call this API in my react app or through postman? I don't understand the endpoints in it.

Deployed a CORS-enabled API for IP geolocation and weather lookup at

```
https://weathersync.herokuapp.com.
```

There are two endpoints:

```
/ip
```

Get the geographic location of the requestor’s IP

```
/weather/$lat,$lng
```

Get weather for a given latitude & longitude

I tried `https://weathersync.herokuapp.com/weather/28.704059,77.102490` in postman but it doesn't work. Also, `https://weathersync.herokuapp.com/?ip=192.168.0.106` doesn't work. Any help is appreciated aI i am new to APIs

Comment: for the ip one, try `https://weathersync.herokuapp.com/192.168.0.106`

Comment: however, you should know that that ip is a local ip, not your externally visible ip

Comment: made get request in postman using https://weathersync.herokuapp.com/192.168.0.106 but it didnt work . error was Could not get any response

Comment: Are you sure that that website is even live and running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through simple trial and error I managed to determine that this API expects you to call it like this for the `/ip` route:

https://weathersync.herokuapp.com/ip?73.119.54.218

Note that this is pretty unusual and would be considered incorrect by most API designers. I would expect it to be `/ip/73.119.54.218` instead, but the server is not set up correctly to handle that.

Also, as TKoL mentioned in the comments, an IP like `192...` will never work, because it is a local IP address that is not visible to the outside world beyond your network. If the server attempts to lookup anything based on that IP address, it will likely not find anything, or even worse it might find something about a computer inside of its datacenter, in which case it could return data that is subtly incorrect from your point of view. You can find your external IP with services like [iplocation.net](https://iplocation.net/find-ip-address).

Your weather example works fine for me as-is (try clicking below in a browser):

https://weathersync.herokuapp.com/weather/28.704059,77.102490

I did not try Postman, but it may not be working for you because it does not send the same HTTP headers as a browser does. Some servers expect certain headers to be sent. You can manually configure the headers in Postman to mimic a browser, which should work if that is the case.